# OpenSSL: error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, wget, tls1.2

`wget -O /Users/itaybd/Finzor_2_26/dev_code/Engine/DATA/EOD/S_temp.zip https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/SHARADAR/SEP?qopts.export=true&api_key=MYKEY` yield OpenSSL: error:1409442E
Where

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json()['tls_version'])
```

Yields: TLS 1.2

How to fix this ????

Comment: How do you expect troubleshooting things if you use two different URLs? Use the same one, write the complete error message ("OpenSSL: error:1409442E" is useless), and remember that the TLS version is not a static property it is a negotiated element at the beginning of any TLS handshake and depends on the capabilities of each endpoints (which then explains that you should not do tests with different URLs otherwise you are comparing apples and oranges).

Answer (score 9):

If your server doesn't support TLS 1.0 you can try running `wget` with the option `--secure-protocol=TLSv1_2`

If your version of `wget` is older than 1.14 and your server uses SNI, upgrade `wget` to at least 1.14.

Please let us know which of these fixes it, and if neither fixes it then let us know more information about the problem (such as the versions of the software you are using including wget and openssl, and the full error from wget).

Comment: Thanks I implemented your advice i.e. using "wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2 -O /Users/itaybd/Finzor_2_26/dev_code/Engine/DATA/EOD/S_temp.zip https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/SHARADAR/SEP?qopts.export=true&api_key=MYKEY" but this runs into Error 403